# VBA convert all cells in column to type text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to do some further formatting to a generated CSV file that's always in the same format. I have a problem with my For Each Loop. the loop deletes an entire row if there is more than one blank row which can be determined from the first column alone.

```
Dim rowCount As Integer
For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells 
    rowCount = rowCount + 1
    '
    ' Delete blank row
    '
    If cell = "" And cell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
        Rows(rowCount + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        spaceCount = 0
    End If
Next
```

At some point the value in the loop one of the calls does not have a value of "", it's just empty and causes it to crash. To solve this I think that changing the type of the cell to text before that compare would work but I can't figure out how (no intellisense!!!)

So how do you convert a cell type in VBA or how else would I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: i forgot to add 
    rowCount = rowCount + 1

Comment: you can just edit your question if you forgot something.

Comment: Declaring the variable cell using `Dim cell As Range` should enable Intellisense. Have you tried to compare `cell.Text = ""`?

Comment: Yeah, cell.text didn't work because cell was something else, no idea what. I did find this - cell.NumberFormat = "@" and I do that to every one in the loop. it doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't get recognised as text so the 2nd line doesn't get deleted.

Comment: What's the error message when it crashes?

Comment: I can't get the same error message back because of changes I made but it basically said that cell needed an object. cell didn't appear to have anything in it, it was like cell = nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cell.Value` instead of the `cell.Text` as it will evaluate the value of the cell regardless of the formating.  Press F1 over `.Value` and `.Text` to read more about both.

Be carefull with the statement `For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells` as you will test every row in the sheet (over a million in Excel 2010) and it could make Excel to crash.

**Edit:**

Consider also the funcion `TRIM`. It removes every empty space before and after a string.  If in the cell there is a white space " "; it will look like empty for the human eye, but it has a space inside therefore is different than "".  If you want to treat it like an empty cell, then try:

```
If Trim(cell.value) = "" then
```

Comment: +1, and I would add a good way to avoid parsing unnecessary cells is `For Each cell In Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)`

Comment: Yeah I stop the for each loop when it reaches 3 blank cells in a row, I left a bunch of the loop calculations out of this question. So you're saying I should use 

If cell.value = "" ...

Comment: Yeah that seems to be working, thanks :). Man I hate VBA, if it was .Net I'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @andy (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248931/andy-holaday) said in a comment, `For Each` is definitely the way to go. This even allows for there to be spaces in between lines.

Example code:

```
Sub ListFirstCol()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

For Each cell In Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
    MsgBox (cell)
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks Andy!